# SOA plugin for netbeans 6.9

Tags: java, netbeans

I need url link to download SOA plugin for netbeans 6.9. Because I don't load the catalogue.xml from the netbeans site.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it may be of help, the plugin is still available for versions greater than 6.7 from this update center: http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/xml/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/updates/updates.xml. Then check the "XML Tools" plugin in the Available Plugins tab.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if they support SOA Feature with the NetBeans after 6.7.
 You may want to use the older version http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansArchivedFeatures

Comment: ok, I've read on the web that netbeans hint of support from v6.5 but you can download the plugin and use it normally. And I need the url to download the plugin.